# Python - urllib3 recieve 403 'Forbidden' while crawling websites

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, urllib3

I am using `Python3` and `urllib3` for crawling and downloading websites. I crawled a list of 4000 different domains and at about 5 of them i got back `HttpErrorCode` -  `403 - 'Forbidden'`.

On my browser the website does exist and respond correctly. Probably these websites are suspecting me as a crawler and forbid me from getting the data.

This is my code:

```
from urllib3 import PoolManager, util, Retry
import certifi as certifi
from urllib3.exceptions import MaxRetryError

manager = PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',
                               ca_certs=certifi.where(),
                               num_pools=15,
                               maxsize=6,
                               timeout=40.0,
                               retries=Retry(connect=2, read=2, redirect=10))
url_to_download = "https://www.uvision.co.il/"
headers = util.make_headers(accept_encoding='gzip, deflate',
                                keep_alive=True,
                                user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0")
headers['Accept-Language'] = "en-US,en;q=0.5"
headers['Connection'] = 'keep-alive'
headers['Accept'] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
try:
    response = manager.request('GET',
                               url_to_download,
                               preload_content=False,
                               headers=headers)
except MaxRetryError as ex:
    raise FailedToDownload()
```

Example of websites that have rejected me:
https://www.uvision.co.il/ and http://www.medyummesut.net/.

Another website that don't work and Throws `MaxRetryError` is:

http://www.nytimes.com/2015/10/28/world/asia/south-china-sea-uss-lassen-spratly-islands.html?hp&action=click&pgtype=Homepage&module=first-column-region&region=top-news&WT.nav=top-news&_r=1

I've also tried to use the exact same headers that Firefox use and it didn't work either. Am i doing here something wrong?

Comment: Added util import and the PoolManager instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify `keep_alive=True`, which adds a header `connection: keep-alive`

You then also add a header `Connection: keep-alive` (note the slight difference in case). And this seems to be causing the problem. To fix it just remove the redundant line

```
headers['Connection'] = 'keep-alive'
```

Comment: Thanks, removing the redundant header fixed it for the first two links. Do you know how to fix the 'nytimes' link. I just figured out that to use this website you have to enable cookies, maybe this is it. How can i do that?

Comment: *How can I do that?*  Upgrade to [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).  `requests` uses urllib3 but adds a lot of nice friendly power, like the ability to automagically handle cookies and SSL.

Comment: That's a separate issue. I know that nytimes limits the number of articles that you can read each month without buying a subscription. Automatic requests will probably be stopped, however https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests has better cookie handling than vanilla urllib3